# Python Syntax Error "Expected indented block"

Tags: python

I would just like to ask for help regarding my code as it is giving me an error which I cannot see. Normally, IDLE would highlight the error but this time, it's not giving me any at all so I am quite confused on where my problem is located.

Also just a headsup, I am quite new to python and have just recently tried it out about 2 days ago so I would be thankful if anyone could help this noob(me) with this problem.

```
import time as t
from os import path

##dest is the string
def createFile(dest):

'''
The script creates a text at the passed in location, names file based on date
'''
    date = t.localtime(t.time())
    ##name=month/day/year
        name = '%d_%d_%d.txt'%(date[1],date[2],(date[0]%100))

    ##if file does not exist
    if not(path,isfile(dest+name)):
    f = open(dest + name, 'w')
    f.write('\n'*30)
    f.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    destination = 'C:\\Python34\\My Projects in Python\\'
    createFile(destination)
    input("done!")
```

Comment: You are mixing tabs and spaces; since Stack Exchange uses *4 spaces* when displaying tabs, your indentation is well mucked up here now.

Comment: @DonkeyKong: that's because there are tabs on those lines, but not on the `if`.

Comment: Your docstring needs indenting too, it needs to be indented to the same level as the rest of the function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Lol, thanks :P great investigative skills I must say.

Comment: I'd suggest switching on _show invisible characters_ in whichever IDE you use. It will make your life easier. Also, stick to 4 spaces.

Comment: Looking more closely at your indentation, your `if` line *is also tab indented*, and that'd be *very* wrong if you really did that.=

Comment: The `name = ` line uses spaces however.

Comment: In summary: your indentation is a big old mess, please configure your editor to only use spaces and convert your existing tabs to spaces. Then fix all indentation issues that remain.

Comment: See http://i.stack.imgur.com/eWlfY.png; solid underlined whitespace is tabs, dotted lines are spaces. I took the source of your original post for this.

Comment: Ah cheers. Will do that now. Thank guys.

Answer (score 0):

You had couple of issues in your code:

1. You need to indent the comment as well
2. You need to move back the name
3. You need to put `path.isfile` instead of `path,isfile`
4. You need to indent 3 lines after your first if

Here's working code:

```
import time as t
from os import path

##dest is the string
def createFile(dest):

    '''
    The script creates a text at the passed in location, names file based on date
    '''
    date = t.localtime(t.time())
    ##name=month/day/year
    name = '%d_%d_%d.txt'%(date[1],date[2],(date[0]%100))

    ##if file does not exist
    if not(path.isfile(dest+name)):
        f = open(dest + name, 'w')
        f.write('\n'*30)
        f.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    destination = 'C:\Python34\My Projects in Python\'
    createFile(destination)
    input("done!")
```